# Java Get the last key pressed

Tags: java, keylistener, keyevent

I'm trying to make a hotkey to control some code but am struggling to access the last key that has been pressed on the keyboard.

I have this setup to save the key code from the last key press:

```
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class KeyLog {
    private static volatile int lastKeyCode = 0;
    
    public static int getLastKeyCode() {
        return lastKeyCode;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {

            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent ke) {
                synchronized (KeyLog.class) {
                    if(ke.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED)
                        lastKeyCode = ke.getKeyCode();
                    }
                    return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And then I check the keycode in this class:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
public class Hotkey{
    
    public void check() throws InterruptedException {
        while(true) {
            if(KeyLog.getLastKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD7){
                System.out.println("Y");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("N");
            }
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Hotkey hotkey = new Hotkey();
        hotkey.check();
    }
}
```

But no matter what I do, my console only outputs "N". I think it's because lastKeyCode isn't getting updated. I tried calling KeyLog.main(null); in the main function of Hotkey but that also didn't work.

Comment: No, it's because you have an infinite loop with `while(true)` which is immediately entered after starting your program because at that point in time there's no key pressed.

Comment: @QBrute Okay, I tried putting the 'while(true)' check loop in a new thread. It still only outputs "N" again and again no matter the buttons I press

Comment: KeyEvents are only dispatch to GUI components that have focus. You can't just run a background class to intercept KeyEvents. In order to do that you need to use a lower level language that has access to the OS. Or you might be able to use jni or jna.

Comment: Did you check that your dispatchKeyEvent is getting called?

Comment: @camickr I feared as much... Thank you!